# SFML 2.1 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error

Tags: c++, sfml

I have recently installed SFML 2.1 and am trying to compile and run from the terminal, NOT Xcode, the sample program that they have on their website at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php.

```
   Path to where I installed SFML:
   /Users/.../Desktop/C++_Code/SMFL/SFML-2.1-osx-gcc-universal
```

However, I keep getting the error of:

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "sf::String::String(char const*, std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
  _main in window-48cb4a.o
```

After googling it, I came across this question: [SFML 2.1 RenderWindow linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910387/sfml-2-1-renderwindow-linking-error)

In the accepted answer, the person said that if I wanted to use g++, I had to download the "GCC" version. So, I proceeded to download the GCC - universal 32+64 bits (OS X 10.5+) version and then followed the instructions for installing and compiling SFML on linux, since there were none for mac (http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php) by doing the following:

Since I had installed SFML in a non-standard location, I told my compiler where to find the header files like so:

```
   -I /Users/.../Desktop/C++_Code/SMFL/SFML-2.1-osx-gcc-universal/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Headers
```

I also had to tell my compiler where to find the SMFL libraries:

```
  -L /Users/.../Desktop/C++_Code/SMFL/SFML-2.1-osx-gcc-universal/lib
```

I needed to also tell the library loader where to find the SFML libraries from:

```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/.../Desktop/C++_Code/SMFL/SFML-2.1-osx-gcc-universal/lib
```

Then, I put the sfml-audio.framework, sfml-window.framework, sfml-graphics.framework, sfml-network.framework, and sfml-system.framework in my Frameworks directory (/Library/Frameworks).

Finally, I tried to compile my program in the following ways:

1. `g++ window.cpp -I /Users/.../Desktop/C++_Code/SMFL/SFML-2.1-osx-gcc-universal/Frameworks/SFML.framework/Headers/SFML -L /users/.../Desktop/C++_Code/SMFL/SFML-2.1-osx-gcc-universal/lib -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-system`
2. `g++ window.cpp -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-system`

But, I keep getting the same error. I have continued to google the error, but all I keep getting are questions where people are using Xcode and not the terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you very much, Joachim Pileborg, for editing my question!

Comment: It seems your pre-built SFML library was built using GCC (and its libstdc++), while you're using Clang (which uses libc++). Either try to find a pre-built version of SFML that was built with Clang and libc++, or download the source and build it yourself. And don't be fooled by you using the command `g++` to build, it's actually `clang++` being used.

Comment: I don't know how Darwin frameworks affect this, but usually to use a library with gcc/g++ you need a `-l` option to specify the library (the `-L` option just specifies a directory to search - the compiler/linker will not search all libraries in there, only specific libs).

Comment: Ah, interesting, I did not know that about g++. Is there something similar to g++ that I could use in order to correctly compile for what I have already without having to re-download SFML again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out at last! First off, as Joachim Pileborg pointed out, I need to install the clang version of SFML for mac since I was using g++ to compile which is clang++ in disguise, as Joachim Pileborg also pointed out. Next, I had to go through the instructions again for setting up SFML with Linux (http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php).

However, the icing on the cake was when I read this question:

[OSX GCC how to specify sfml library source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090674/osx-gcc-how-to-specify-sfml-library-source)

...and this question:

[FreeType error when building in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651769/freetype-error-when-building-in-xcode)

...which got me thinking: maybe I should try moving my freetype.framework folder (which can be found in the extlibs directory) into my /Library/Frameworks directory. Once I did this and compiled using

```
g++ window.cpp -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-system
```

It compiled and ran successfully!!! I am very happy now!