# SFML not found - CLion/Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

I'm basically trying to make an SFML project in CLion which uses CMake.

I first downloaded SFML 2.2 which already had the `.dylib` files built. It said to install them in `usr/local/lib` and `usr/local/include`, but they didn't exist, so I created them and then put the files there.

I then opened up CLion, created a subdirectoy `cmake_modules`, placed the `FindSFML.cmake` file inside, and in the root project directory placed these files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::err() << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloWorld ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics window system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${SFML_Libraries})
```

The problem is that when I try to build the project, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sf::err()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried searching for a solution, but none of them seem to be working. Did I put the files in the wrong place, or did I forget some import CMake setting? I know that setting SFML up with Xcode would be easier, but I'd prefer to use CLion if at all possible.

Comment: Did you see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436761/sfml-2-1-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error?

Comment: @Tsyvarev that link didn't really help, I found another one here: http://goobbe.com/questions/4676434/how-to-run-sfml-in-clion-error-undefined-reference-to and copied the makefile configuration at the bottom exactly, but now it says `fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found`

Comment: Oh it also says `make[3]: *** No rule to make target /Users/Rutvik/Downloads/SFML-2.3/lib/libsfml-system.dylib`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I made an entirely new project, ran `xcode-select --install` on my terminal to make `/usr/local/` a directory that gets searched by the compiler, downloaded SFML 2.3 instead of 2.2, decided to use the `FindSFML.cmake` file shipped *with* SFML, and made my `CmakeLists.txt` file look like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(SFMLTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SFMLTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "~/SFML-2.3/cmake/Modules/")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED graphics window system)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(SFMLTest ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif(SFML_FOUND)
```

This compiled and ran the following code in CLion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Window");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what exactly fixed everything, but I'm just glad it did. Hopefully this helps anyone else who's in a similar jam.

Answer (score 2):

For SFML 2.5 and greater a more modern approach has been taken and setting up cmake is easier.

***Example CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(SFMLTest)

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
add_executable(SFMLTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SFMLTest sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

Note :

> Its no longer needed to setup FindSFML.cmake or SFML_ROOT etc.
>
> SFML_LIBRARIES, SFML_DEPENDENCIES and SFML_INCLUDE_DIR don't exist
> anymore

More info https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0

Answer (score 0):

For others who downloaded SFML via brew, I managed to fix this by adding this to my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SFML_ROOT /usr/local/lib)
```

Comment: I am stuck with this and I downloaded SFML through brew, any help?